# Connected to Mongo Successfully Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, thunderclient

Trying to get the user details by id from the mongodb server which i have created but the id is undefined.

```
//get user details from mongodb server
router.post("/getuser", fetchuser, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.user.id;
    const user = await User.findById(userId).select("-password");
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

```
//fetchuser middleware code
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const JWT_SECRET = '';

const fetchuser = (req, res, next) => {
    // Get the user from the jwt token and add id to req object
    const token = req.header('auth-token');
    if (!token) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Please authenticate using a valid token" })
    }
    try {
        const data = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET);
        req.user = data.user;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Please authenticate using a valid token" })
    }
}


module.exports = fetchuser;
```

I want a fix for the undefined id link to the project uploaded in github `https://github.com/nirmalyax/notebook-backend`

[Screenshot.]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDOAM.png

Comment: Can you check that id is exist or not not in your db. May be it is in different format. Could you please connect with your db from mongodb compass and see that id is exist or not. Please add screershot

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: Could you please print that user object you received from database.

Comment: If you are trying to access it from response then you can access it like user._id

Comment: its giving the same error undefined '_id'

Comment: Please print response object and show me

Comment: I have no clue of what you are asking for as i am new to this can you please guide me with the following

Comment: const user = await User.findById(userId).select("-password");
add one console statement to print this user

Comment: { user: null } user is comming null

Comment: But when I am using `const userId = req.body.id;
    const user = await User.findOne(userId).select("-password");`                              its is taking the first id form the data base for every auth-token i am giving.

Comment: To make sure you have the id you expcect, try `console.log(userId)` right before the findOne, and maybe try `findById` instead of `findOne`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use body-parser middleware to parse incoming request bodies in JSON format (bodyParser.json()) and URL-encoded data (bodyParser.urlencoded()).
Install body-parser via npm if you haven't :

```
   npm install body-parser
```

Then, use it in your Express application like this:

```
 const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

//  you  can use body-parser middleware here to parse incoming request
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 



app.listen(port);
```